# SSRS Hide Columns Based on Time Expression

Tags: time, reporting-services, expression, hide, visibility

I have a 2 sheet report and want SSRS to hide columns from sheet1 and sheet2 based on the time of day.

Steps and Issue:
I added an expression to hide columns and data in sheet2.  If the report runs after 12:00:00 PM all columns are displayed. The issue is when I schedule before 12:00:00 PM the columns are not hidden.

I added the following expression where if report is run prior to 12:00:00 PM local time hide else show.
I left out the date parameter since the report is only run 1x/month.

Sheet1: Hide columns

1. Selecting column from tablix
2. Right-Click choose 'Column Properties'
3. Select 'Visiblity'
4. Select 'Show or hide based on expression
5. Added expression: =IIF(Globals!ExecutionTime <"12:00:00:00 PM",true,false)

Sheet2: Hide sheet

1. Select rectangle where the tablix is placed
2. Right-Click and select 'Rectangle Properties'
3. Select 'Visiblity'
4. Select 'Show or hide based on expression
5. Added expression: =IIF(Globals!ExecutionTime <"12:00:00:00 PM",true,false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Globals!ExecutionTime` will return the date and time that the report started execution, not just the time. Your expression compares with just a time so it will compare the default system date (or whatever it's called, it'll be something 1900-01-01) at 12:00:00 to your execution date/time so it will always appear as 'after' the time you specified.

You can solve this very easily by using something like

```
=HOUR(Globals!ExecutionTime)<12
```

Here we just extract the hour from the execution datetime and check if it's less than 12

Also note that as this will return a boolean, there is no need for the `IIF()`